# exec "`dirname "$0"`"/../../waf "$@"

Tags: linux, terminal, ns-3

I am new to ns3. i have some simple programs written in c++.

I run my ns3 program  by below command

```
exec "`dirname "$0"`"/../../waf "$@"
```

Can anyone explain function of above mentioned line?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @ Anders Lindahl  can you explain  "`dirname "$0"`"/../../waf "$@" line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
dirname "$0"
```

gets the directory name of file containing the command.

```
"`dirname "$0"`"/../../waf
```

appends `/../../waf` to the result obtained by `dirname "$0"`.

So it you obtained `/some/arbitray/path` from the previous command, this would return `/some/arbitray/path/../../waf`

```
exec "`dirname "$0"`"/../../waf "$@"
```

replaces the shell with the command obtained above and passes the arguments that were passed to the script containing the original command.

---

As an example, if your command was in a file contained in a directory `/d1/d2/d3/d4/d5` and you executed it by saying:

```
sh myfile foo bar "foo bar"
```

then the command being executed would be:

```
/d1/d2/d3/d4/d5/../../waf foo bar "foo bar"
```

Comment: Another exmaple: `cd $(dirname $0)/..`  gets the directory name of the shell script file containing the command, and the add `/..` to it. So we got the parent folder of the folder containing the shell script.